# Differentiate $y=x^{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus

$y=x^{\sqrt{x}}$

1) Take natural logarithms of both sides of the equation $y=f(x)$ and use the Laws of Logarithm to simplify

$\ln\ y=\sqrt{x}\cdot \ln x$

2) Differentiate implicitly to respect to x

$\frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x}$

3) Solve the resulting equation for y'

$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\cdot(\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x})$

$x^{\sqrt{x}}\cdot(\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x})$

Why is the answer in the book different?

Comment: How exactly did find the derivative of $\sqrt{x} \ln x$?

Comment: What is the answer from the book? Maybe they are equivalent?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom u'v + v'u , ok ?

Comment: You only took $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)$ when you need to take $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the product rule when differentiating $\sqrt{x} \ln x$. This gives you the derivative $$\frac{1}{x} \sqrt{x} +  \frac{\ln x}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your implicit differentiation on the right side was incorrect.  Note that
$$
\frac d{dx}\left[ \sqrt{x}\ln(x)\right] = 
\frac{1}{2\sqrt x} \ln x + \sqrt{x} \frac 1x
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$lny=\sqrt { x } lnx\\ \left( lny \right) ^{ \prime  }=\frac { lnx }{ 2\sqrt { x }  } +\frac { \sqrt { x }  }{ x } =\frac { lnx+2 }{ 2\sqrt { x }  } \\ \frac { y^{ \prime  } }{ y } =\frac { lnx+2 }{ 2\sqrt { x }  } \\ { y }^{ \prime  }={ x }^{ \sqrt { x }  }\left( \frac { lnx+2 }{ 2\sqrt { x }  }  \right) $$